# Extracting / unzipping files to folders with date / time stamp with 7zip 7z

Tags: date, batch-file, time, 7zip

I am using 7zip command line in a batch file to extract zip files to folders of the same name as the zip file and output the folders to a destination directory:  I've tried a few variations without success including

```
7za x "%directory_destination%*.zip" -o%directory_destination%\%date%*"

7za x "%directory_destination%\*.zip" -o%directory_destination%\*"
```

I am having trouble including the current %date% and %time% in the folder name of the extracted zip file.

For example, the contents of a zip file called abc.zip should be extracted to a folder called abc_18.10.14_7.34 etc.

Comment: %date% isnt in your code so no wonder it isnt working, please provide your current working command line.

Comment: Hi toby I've tried a few variations without success including 7za x "%directory_destination%\*.zip" -o%directory_destination%\%date%*" Im just not sure how to format date and time with the folder names.

Comment: This stackoverflow answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/865568/6244

Comment: Hi Toby sorry this did not help! Any further guidance would be most appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi user3785396 you need to supply more information

Comment: Hi Toby

I understand how to format date / time variables as I use them in batch files (see below) but I don’t understand how to apply it to:

    7za x "%directory_destination%\*.zip" -o%directory_destination%\*"

Date / Time Variables:

rem set month=%date:~7,2%
rem set yearlong=%date:~-4%
rem set hour=%time:~0,2%
rem set minute=%time:~3,2%
rem set second=%time:~6,2%

rem %yearlong%.%month% %hour%.%minute%.%second%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63273/discussion-between-user3785396-and-toby-allen).

Comment: I don't want to chat I want you to write a question that can be answered. Put the information you have given me in your question. If you make your question answerable someone will answer it.

Comment: Hi Toby. I didn't mean to click the chat option. I clicked it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Test this on some sample files:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

cd /d "c:\folder with zip files\"
set "directory_destination=c:\target\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.zip /b /a-d ') do (
   md "%directory_destination%\%%~na_%dd%.%mm%.%yyyy%_%hh%.%min%%%~xa" 2>nul
   7za x "%%a" -o"%directory_destination%\%%~na_%dd%.%mm%.%yyyy%_%hh%.%min%%%~xa"
)
pause
```