# Batch script to rename file with timestamp on FTP server after upload

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have this script in a batch file that uploads a local file to our FTP server. I need to rename `myfile.csv` to suffix the date and time in this format `YYYYMMDDHHMM` e.g. `myfile_201701041333.csv`. How can this be done?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=myserver
Set _UserName=myusername
Set _Password=mypassword
Set _LocalFolder=\\data\myfolder
Set _RemoteFolder=e-download
Set _Filename=myfile.csv
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
 >"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo put %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
```

Comment: ...just a side note: you could put all `echo` command inside of a parenthesised block `( )` and redirect the entire block once by `> "%_ScriptFile%"`...

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorted and working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864718/how-to-append-a-date-in-batch-files for required date code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `put` command accepts an optional second argument to specify a target name:

```
put localfile remotefile
```

In your batch file that would be:

```
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo put %_Filename% %_Remotename%
```

To set the `%_Remotename%` to the timestamped name, see
[Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1192476/850848) – Prefer the `wmic` or PowerShell-based solutions, as the `%date%`-based solutions are not locale independent.

---

Your task would be a way more easier with some more advanced FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) it's as easy as:

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=myserver
Set _UserName=myusername
Set _Password=mypassword
Set _LocalFolder=\\data\myfolder
Set _RemoteFolder=e-download
Set _Filename=myfile.csv

winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://%_UserName%:%_Password%@%_FTPServerName%/" ^
    "put ""%_LocalFolder%\%_Filename%"" ""%_RemoteFolder%/myfile_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnn%%.csv""" ^
    "exit"
```

References:

- [Automate file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

(I'm the author of WinSCP)

Answer (score 1):

Using the command `wmic os get localdatetime /value` you can get an ouput that almost directly suits your desire. Now with some extra code you can trim it to your perfect fit:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=.= tokens=2" %%n in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do (
set var=%%n
set var=!var:~0,-2!
)
echo %var%
```

For every output in the command above take the text between `=` and `.`. Save that text to the variable var, trim the last 2 characters to remove the seconds.

Now you can do something like:

```
ren myfile.csv myfile_%var%.csv
```

to rename it.